# About "LOCKED MODE" (COPY INTO LOCKED)

Tags: monetdb

Is the "lock" done on the entire database or only on the table involved in "COPY INTO"?
In case it is done only on the involved table: Can I have more than one connection in MonetDB, guaranteeing that only the "COPY INTO" connection will access the table that is being filled?

I ask this because in the documentation it says that when using the "LOCKED MODE" I have to ensure that there is only one connection in MonetDB (the entire database).
But, this doesn't seem to make sense because usually a "COPY INTO" command uses only one table.

Thanks.

Alexandre.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use it.  It has very specific requirements not well-documented.  In my 10+ year experience with COPY INTO, it barely gives me any noticeable benefits (over the trouble I have to go through).